# Set a fixed node in Quartz Scheduler cluster

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

Is it possible to set a fixed node for executing tasks in Quartz scheduler? It should be some kind of active-active cluster so all tasks are executed by the same node; the second node(or rest of nodes) should remain as backup just in case the main one stops working. If this occurs, a new fixed node should be choosed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This functionality is not currently available in the open-source Quartz scheduler version. It seems to be only available in the [commercial version](https://www.terracotta.org/products/quartz-scheduler) (search for "Quartz Where").